# Is there any inbuilt function available to run the source synchronize in apache flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are newbie for Apache Flink and Scala. Here is our use case like we are sow the data from AMPS Server (crankuptheamps) with two type of topic initially. Source #1 & #2 pulling the data from topic #1 & #2 .

Use Case

our requirement is nothing but initially source #1 will sow(state of world) the data before source two start. because we are just storing the source #1 data into Map State. Then only we need to start the source #2 sow operation. Ultimately we need to run the source one by one. So is there any options available to run the source one by one.

```
def sourceConnect(environment: StreamExecutionEnvironment,topic: String, subscriptionType: SubscriptionType): DataStream[Map[String, String]] = {

val dataStream : DataStream[Map[String, String]] = environment.addSource(new RichSourceFunction[Map[String,String]]()  {

  var sourceClient: Client = null

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    // .... Code Here
  }

  override def run(sourceContext: SourceFunction.SourceContext[Map[String, String]]): Unit = {
    subscriptionType match {

      case SubscriptionType.sow =>
          //.... Code Here

    }
  }

  override def getRuntimeContext: RuntimeContext = super.getRuntimeContext

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
    sourceClient.close()
  }

  override def close(): Unit = try cancel()
  finally super.close()

})
dataStream }
```

---

```
    private var environment: StreamExecutionEnvironment = null

     // .... Code Here

     val source1 = environment.addSource(....)
     val source2 = environment.addSource(....)

     val conn = source1.connect(source2)

     conn.print()

     environment.execute()
```

Eventually our use case as simply as to run the source1 first and source2 which means synchronize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particularly wonderful way in Flink to ingest one stream before starting to read from another. This general topic is often referred to as *side inputs*, and there is a FLIP (a FLink Improvement Proposal) [on this subject](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-17+Side+Inputs+for+DataStream+API).

So far, the best resource on this topic is a talk given at Flink Forward San Francisco 2018 by Gregory Fee from Lyft on [Bootstrapping State In Apache Flink](https://www.da-platform.com/flink-forward/resources/bootstrapping-state-in-apache-flink) that explores several possible approaches. Which one might be best depends on your specific application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd previously hacked up a [UnionedSources](https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/flink-streaming-kmeans/blob/master/src/main/java/com/scaleunlimited/flinksources/UnionedSources.java) `SourceFunction` that lets me first send in all the data from one source, and then the data from a subsequent source. I used this for bootstrapping some state. Maybe this would work for your use case.

-- Ken